# Stay open menu after checked item

Tags: android

I have created a menu in which dynamically added submenus and several items with setCheckable. I would like to stay open menu when I click on point 1/2/3.

```
SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 1101, "select");
subMenu.add("point 1").setCheckable(true);
subMenu.add("point 2").setCheckable(true);
subMenu.add("point 3").setCheckable(true);
```

Now, when I choose a position, the menu is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how to keep main menu whiling selecting sub menu. But i have an alternative idea.

You can call menu click event Programatically once the sub menu clicked. So your main menu will get pop up once the sub menu clicked

Code to call main menu Programatically

`MenuItem actionRestart = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_restart);
onOptionsItemSelected(actionRestart);`

Hope it will hep you...